# Calculating and aggregating data by date/time

Tags: pyspark, etl, data-warehouse, databricks

I am working with a dataframe like this:

```
Id     | TimeStamp         | Event     |  DeviceId
1      | 5.2.2019 8:00:00  | connect   |  1
2      | 5.2.2019 8:00:05  | disconnect|  1
```

I am using databricks and pyspark to do the ETL process. How can I calculate and create such a dataframe as shown at the bottom? I have already tried using a UDF but I could not find a way to make it work. I also tried to do it by iterating over the whole data frame, but this is extremely slow.

I want to aggregate this dataframe to get a new dataframe which tells me the times, how long each device has been connected and disconnected:

```
Id     | StartDateTime   | EndDateTime   | EventDuration  |State    |  DeviceId
1      | 5.2.19 8:00:00  | 5.2.19 8:00:05| 0.00:00:05     |connected|  1
```

Comment: can we expect that there is a connect and disconnect for every DeviceId?

Comment: @gaw yes we always have either connect or disconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make this work with a `window` function and some further column creations with `withColumn`.

The code I did should create the mapping for devices and create a table with the duration for each state. The only requirement is that connect and disconnect appear alternatively.

Then you can use the following code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import datetime
test_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,datetime.datetime(2019,2,5,8),"connect",1),
(2,datetime.datetime(2019,2,5,8,0,5),"disconnect",1),
(3,datetime.datetime(2019,2,5,8,10),"connect",1),
(4,datetime.datetime(2019,2,5,8,20),"disconnect",1),], 
["Id","TimeStamp","Event","DeviceId"])    
#creation of dataframe with 4 events for 1 device
test_df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+----------+--------+
| Id|          TimeStamp|     Event|DeviceId|
+---+-------------------+----------+--------+
|  1|2019-02-05 08:00:00|   connect|       1|
|  2|2019-02-05 08:00:05|disconnect|       1|
|  3|2019-02-05 08:10:00|   connect|       1|
|  4|2019-02-05 08:20:00|disconnect|       1|
+---+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

Then you can create the helper functions and the window:

```py
my_window = Window.partitionBy("DeviceId").orderBy(col("TimeStamp").desc()) #create window
get_prev_time = lag(col("Timestamp"),1).over(my_window)                     #get previous timestamp
time_diff = get_prev_time.cast("long") - col("TimeStamp").cast("long")      #compute duration

test_df.withColumn("EventDuration",time_diff)\
.withColumn("EndDateTime",get_prev_time)\           #apply the helper functions
.withColumnRenamed("TimeStamp","StartDateTime")\    #rename according to your schema
.withColumn("State",when(col("Event")=="connect", "connected").otherwise("disconnected"))\ #create the state column 
.filter(col("EventDuration").isNotNull()).select("Id","StartDateTime","EndDateTime","EventDuration","State","DeviceId").show()
#finally some filtering for the last events, which do not have a previous time
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------+
| Id|      StartDateTime|        EndDateTime|EventDuration|       State|DeviceId|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------+
|  3|2019-02-05 08:10:00|2019-02-05 08:20:00|          600|   connected|       1|
|  2|2019-02-05 08:00:05|2019-02-05 08:10:00|          595|disconnected|       1|
|  1|2019-02-05 08:00:00|2019-02-05 08:00:05|            5|   connected|       1|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great and I appreciate the effort you put into answering my question in such detail